# Why doesn't the code after this promise invocation run?

Tags: javascript, jquery-deferred

When I try to add any code after handing a function to a promise to run when it finishes, it never runs. See this example.

```
(function() {
   var url = //some url that I know works

   var promise = $.get(url);
   $.when(promise).then(function(xml) {
      alert("Promise resolved.");
   })();

   //This code doesn't run!
   alert("Code after promise.");
})();
```

I thought that execution immediately went to the next line after `$.when`. Isn't that the whole point of using promises? The "Promise resolved" alert goes off fine, but the "Code after promise" never appears. What am I missing?

Comment: check your developer console, there WILL be an error

Comment: Unless this is not jQuery, you need a $ in front of `(function() {`.

Comment: I bet your error is regarding calling something that's **not** a function.

Comment: @GhostCoder20 No he doesn't need a '$` at the front, look at the last line: it's an immediately-invoked anonymous function.

Comment: the answers should solve it, but regarding @JaromandaX comment - I am sure there was an error thrown in your console that would of prevented the eed for a question

Comment: All good points. Thanks for the feedback everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unnecessary `()` after this block:

```
$.when(promise).then(function(xml) {
    alert("Promise resolved.");
  })();
```

Change it to:

```
$.when(promise).then(function(xml) {
    alert("Promise resolved.");
  });
```

One of the comments stated that you need a `$` at the beginning of your code. This is not true. You are simply creating a closure here, and this is perfectly acceptable syntax for such. I would, however, recommend prefixing your script with a `;` so that if it is included after any other closures, it ensures that they are closed. This is just generally good practice when using closures in JavaScript.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. You're just passing a function to then(), so you don't need parentheses at the end to call it like the closure.

Thanks for the tip about the semi colon at the top.

Comment: You got it! The () at the end of your closure is to tell JS that it's an anonymous function. Functions are always defined with a () through which arguments can be passed. You can actually pass in arguments to an anonymous function like yours. In this case they will get passed in to that first function, which is great for exposing global objects and libraries and such, since the function can't see outside of its own scope (except to objects bound to the window).

i.e.

`;(function(modernizr){
  alert(modernizr.touch);
})(Modernizr);`

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
   var url = //some url that I know works

   var promise = $.get(url);
   //********************************
   $.when(promise).then(function(xml){
   alert("Promise resolved.");
   }); // take this () off
   //********************************
   //This code will run first
   alert("Code after promise.");
 })();
```